# Java - How to deal with a large amout of teams ? (Bukkit Plugin)

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to make a clean code consisting of team management for a Bukkit plugin.
I already saw this topic here to help me : https://bukkit.org/threads/how-to-make-teams.248795/#post-2362503
But I don't have any idea on how to handle a larger amount of teams without a crappy and very long code. The total of player is 100, in a couple of modes (solo, duo, squads)

Do you have any idea/tutorial on how to handle this amount of team and how to treat them in an efficient way ? I mean the declaration, not the Bukkit-specific handling!

Because I started to declare shady things like  "List teamx = new ArrayList();" a hundred times and I know this is not the way of doing things :)
Thanks

Comment: Why not a list of lists (i.e. `List<ArrayList<String>>`)? Or better yet, why not create a `Team` class that includes a well-written object-oriented declaration for a team's state, including its players *and* its other data?

Comment: Wouldn't this make the auto assignation and friendly fire checks harder to code ?

Comment: I don't write Minecraft mods so I wouldn't know the APIs offhand. My remarks are based on general principles for readable and maintainable Java that I picked up in the workplace. If there's some strong reason why a raw `List<String>` is the best solution then it might be a good idea; however this clearly does not scale with the number of teams, which you discovered with the "shady things" you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the advices! It is all working now :)